# SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22 Unknown column in 'field list' error Java Spring Boot Mysql error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Basically  I am trying to make a simple promotion page, The error that I am getting is SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22  Error is Unknown column 'promotion0_.promo_type_id' in 'field list'

Here are the model classes

```
package promotions.model;


import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="promotion")
public class Promotion implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;
private String name;
private boolean active;
private boolean status;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="promoType_id")
private Promo_Type promo_Type;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="roomType_id")
private RoomType room_Types;



public Promotion() {

}
public Promotion(String name, boolean active, boolean status, Promo_Type promo_Type, RoomType room_Types) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.active = active;
    this.status = status;
    this.promo_Type = promo_Type;
    this.room_Types = room_Types;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}
public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}
public boolean isStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(boolean status) {
    this.status = status;
}
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "promoType_id")
public Promo_Type getPromo_Type() {
    return promo_Type;
}

public void setPromo_Type(Promo_Type promo_Type) {
    this.promo_Type = promo_Type;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "roomType_id")
public RoomType getRoom_Types() {
    return room_Types;
}
public void setRoom_Types(RoomType room_Types) {
    this.room_Types = room_Types;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Promotions [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", active=" + active + ", status=" + status + ", promo_Type="
            + promo_Type + ", room_Types=" + room_Types + "]";
}
```

}

```
package promotions.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="roomType")
public class RoomType implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="roomType_id")
private int id;
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="room_Types", cascade= CascadeType.ALL,fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<Promotion>promotions;




public RoomType() {

}

public RoomType(String name, Collection<Promotion> promotions) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.promotions = promotions;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Collection<Promotion> getPromotions() {
    return promotions;
}

public void setPromotions(Collection<Promotion> promotions) {
    this.promotions = promotions;
}






}
```

here is another model class

```
package promotions.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="promoType")
public class Promo_Type implements Serializable{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="promoType_id")
private int id;
private String name;
private double discount;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="promo_Type", cascade= CascadeType.ALL,fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<Promotion>promotions;



public Promo_Type() {

}
public Promo_Type(String name, double discount, Collection<Promotion>      promotions) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.discount = discount;
    this.promotions = promotions;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public double getDiscount() {
    return discount;
}
public void setDiscount(double discount) {
    this.discount = discount;
}
public Collection<Promotion> getPromotions() {
    return promotions;
}
public void setPromotions(Collection<Promotion> promotions) {
    this.promotions = promotions;
}
```

}

and here is the mysql query

```
 CREATE DATABASE `promotiondb`;

use promotiondb;

CREATE TABLE `promoType` (
  `promoType_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `discount` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`promoType_id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `roomType` (
  `roomType_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`roomType_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `promotion` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `status` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  `active` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  `promoType_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `roomType_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_promoType` (`promoType_id`),
  KEY `fk_roomType` (`roomType_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_roomType` FOREIGN KEY (`roomType_id`) REFERENCES `roomType` (`roomType_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_promoType` FOREIGN KEY (`promoType_id`) REFERENCES `promoType` (`promoType_id`)
);
```

Here is the error, SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22, Unknown column 'promotion0_.promo_type_id' in 'field list'ERROR 34768 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'promotion0_.promo_type_id' in 'field list'

```
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'promotion0_.promo_type_id' in 'field list'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar:5.1.41]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar:5.1.41]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar:5.1.41]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar:5.1.41]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar:5.1.41]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar:5.1.41]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar:5.1.41]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2501) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar:5.1.41]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar:5.1.41]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar:5.1.41]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2117) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:50) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:329) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:74) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at promotions.service.PromotionsService.findAll(PromotionsService.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
at promotions.service.PromotionsService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f95c210e.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at promotions.service.PromotionsService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$30594b1.findAll(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at promotions.controller.SampleRestController.allpromotions(SampleRestController.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.6-dev]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[catalina.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[catalina.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[catalina.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[catalina.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.6-dev]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.6-dev]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.6-dev]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.6-dev]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.6-dev]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_121]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.6-dev]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your problem comes from the config(application.properties) used by SpringBoot in naming your column in your database. Actually if you want to solve this problem, you have to either avoid capital letters in your column name or change your Naming strategy in your application.properties
and use this

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is you problem I mean with your output

Comment: ok you are using the method toString() on a collection and that is the default behaviour of toString on a collection now if you want to display it otherwise there is another way of doing it like taking each element of the collection and display it attribut. If you don't know how to do so you can still contact me I will show you how you can perform that.

Comment: Well I understood that and I solved that part by using the toString function for the PromoType and RoomType model classes, Now I am struggling with bootstrap. I want to a simple promotion page with the CRUD functionality. DO I have to create service classes for each model class? I didn't find too many examples regarding this

Comment: yeah for all your model classes you need a DAO class and a service class. the DAO is about all your direct interaction with your DB. and the service uses DAO to perform your bussiness

Comment: Now I can see the list of the promotion but can't update or create a new promotion this is my service class[link](https://codeshare.io/5vAqJW) this is the MainController [link](https://codeshare.io/5XLMzM) and this is the index.jsp [link](https://codeshare.io/5ONp1P)

Comment: yes the error is SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
2017-04-08 19:16:33.633 ERROR 36780 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'promoType_id' cannot be null
2017-04-08 19:16:33.648 ERROR 36780 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null];

Comment: I tried by using 1,2 in the promo_Type but getting the same error. I think it would have been better If I could have a drop down menu of both the model promotype and roomtype in the promotion for the update purposes. I need to figure out how

Comment: ok It is normal as promoType_id is a foreign key for promotion you need to insert one or two promoType and then use their id in your promotions. so your promoType_id in promotion should reference something in the table PromoType

Comment: I did this at first then I started to make the app. promoType_id   name discount 1 Early Bird 30
2 Last Minute 5
3 72-Hours Promo 15
4 Express Tonight 12
5 Customized 15 so in the create new promotion page , what value should I put in the promo_type, the id numbers right? 1 to 5 or something els

Comment: Hello I've bee off line for the weekend. you need to create and instance of PromoType using one of the id you have in your table promoType, then set the attribut promoType of promotion with the instance you just created

Comment: ok cool, Should I do it in the controller class or in the service class?

Comment: service class. where you have your bussiness actually

Comment: Well I tried this in the promotionservice class, public void save(Promotion promotion, int promoType_id, int roomType_id) {
  promo_Type = new Promo_Type(promoType_id);
  roomType = new RoomType(roomType_id);
  promotionsRepository.save(promotion);
 }  error in the browser Validation failed for object='promotion'.

Comment: Bro thanks a lot. but I am trying to solve it but the error is still there.

Comment: have you tested this at the service layout? I mean it is better to test each layout this alow you to easily debug when ther is a problem

Comment: Bro I think I didn't do it correctly the way you said to me about having an instance of the promotype object. I have posted in one of the previous comment. Was it the correct way?

Comment: Is it okay? but having the same error now it's Column 'promoType_id' cannot be null, public void save(Promotion promotion) {
  
  promo_Type= new Promo_Type(promoType_id);
  roomType = new RoomType(roomType_id);
  promotion = new Promotion(name,false,false,promo_Type,roomType);
  promotionsRepository.save(promotion);
 }

Comment: can you show me your code through code share as you did last time?

Comment: Yes sure, [link](https://codeshare.io/5XLVrz) [link](https://codeshare.io/G64eJ0) [link](https://codeshare.io/29b8zM) [link](https://codeshare.io/5Q8Bzm)

Comment: Here it is [link](https://codeshare.io/29b8A1) and also the roomtype [link](https://codeshare.io/anAdx3)

Comment: bro did you had the time to check the link. I have posted them

Comment: sorry not yet but tomorrow I shall do it

Comment: I suggest that instead of doing like this    "promotype= new Promotype(promotypeid);"   you rather do like this "promotype = promotypeRepository.findOne(1)". Moreover where is the value of  promotypeid in "promotype= new Promotype(promotypeid);"? you have to set a value like promotypeid = 1; or just "promotype= new Promotype(1);" and make sure there is a line in your table prometype with id 1 and do the same with "RoomType"

Comment: Wonderful.. It worked.. What exactly happened behind the screen

Answer (score 11):

Encountered same error, changed on the *application.properties* from

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: none
```

to

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
```

Hope it works for you. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="promoType_id", referencedColumnName="promoType_id")
private Promo_Type promo_Type;
```

Comment: I have just tried this but I am having the same error... "Unknown column 'promotion0_.promo_type_id' in 'field list'"