# What am I mapping incorrectly? Unknown column in the 'field list'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying re-create an older J2EE project with Spring Boot as a learning exercise and have been stuck on this mapping issue for a bit. When I try to extract Result Set for my `User` entity, I keep running into **Unknown column 'user0_.user_id' in 'field list'** and similarly with `Product` entity as well.

Please take a look at my schema.

[image: EER diagram for my schema]

And here are my entities:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int userId;
    
    private String firstName;
    
    private String lastName;
    
    private String email;
    
    private String username;
    
    private String password;
    
    private String roleName;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userJ")
    private List<Card> cards;

    //constructors and getters/setters....
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Card {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int cardId;
    
    private String cardNumber;
    
    private String cardType;
    
    private String expiryMonth;
    
    private String expiryYear;
    
    private String cardHolder;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User userJ;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cardJ")
    private List<Purchase> purchases;
    
    //constructors and getters/setters....
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Purchase {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int purchaseId;
    
    private String notes;
    
    @Basic
    private Timestamp purchaseDate;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cardId")
    private Card cardJ;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="purchaseJ")
    private List<PurchaseItem> purchaseItems;
    
    //constructors and getters/setters....
}
```

```
@Entity
public class PurchaseItem {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int purchaseItemId;
    
    private int quantity;
    
    private BigDecimal price;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="purchaseId")
    private Purchase purchaseJ;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="productId")
    private Product productJ;
    
    //constructors and getters/setters....
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    
    @Id
    private String productId;
    
    private String manufacturer;
    
    private String item;
    
    private String description;
    
    private BigDecimal price;
    
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1)")
    private byte available;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productJ")
    private List<PurchaseItem> purchaseItems;
    
    //constructors and getters/setters....
}
```

My DAO:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    @Autowired
    public EntityManager eman;
    
    @Override
    public List<User> showUsers() {
        
        return eman.createQuery("Select u from User u", User.class).getResultList();
    }

}
```

My Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SheridanSportsRESTController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;
    
    @Autowired
    private ProductDAO productDAO;
    
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> showUsers(){
        
        return userDAO.showUsers();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/products")
    public List<Product> showProducts(){
        
        return productDAO.showProducts();
    }
}
```

And I did not use `@ManyToMany` on my join table because of the extra properties in `PurchaseItem`.

Comment: @Abhay Could you please show your hibernate config. What database do you use?

Comment: @SternK I don't have a hibernate configuration file. I just declared the url and credentials in my application.properties file. And I am using MySQL

Comment: @Abhay use `@Column` annotations & map table columns with `@Entity` fields. You have userId as field but your schema might be expecting UserId column mapping. If your tables already exists, then you must use `@Column`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing the naming strategy in my application.properties file as mentioned in [SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22 Unknown column in 'field list' error Java Spring Boot Mysql error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270058/sql-error-1054-sqlstate-42s22-unknown-column-in-field-list-error-java-sprin)

Thank you all for your help and the vital information regardless.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the column annotation in the userId property like this:

```
@Column(name="UserId")
private Integer userId;
```

This is because when in a class annotated as @Entity, when you do not annotate a column, if it is camelcase according to the java standard, it transforms userId into user_id, adding underscores ().

Since your column is not named like that, you need to specify the name with the @Column annotation.

I recommend that you define the id as a non-primitive data type because you will need to set the value null.

Comment: Alternatively, you can specify a column naming strategy instead of manually coding this on the entity.

Comment: can you indicate how?

Comment: See for example https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-field-naming-spring-boot